# Array of Structures in C

Tags: c, arrays, structure

How would I go about changing this code into an array of structures that holds 25 records?
I am familiar with structures however I am unsure as to how to declare and call an array of structures. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct household_t
{
    int  ID ;  
    int  Income ;  
    int  Members ; 
}  houset;

void  show_house ( houset ) ;

int main ( void) 
{
    houset  house = {1990 , 12180 , 5} ;
    show_house ( house );
    return 0 ;
}

void show_house ( houset  passed_house ) 
{
     printf ("\n\nID      Income  Members") ;
     printf ("\n\n%d      %d      %d \n\n\n", 
       passed_house.ID ,
       passed_house.Income ,
       passed_house.Members );
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Just like any other array: `houset arrOf[10];` declares an array of 10 `houset` structs...

Comment: but the 10 should be 25, because he wants 25 records :)

Comment: To the OP: Please note that the accepted answer might lead you to the infamous problem, after which this site was named: [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow). The more your program grows, the more likely it'll become your stack overflows. Do read through my answer, it explains a way to fix that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do, is create an array, like any other array:

```
houset hose_array[25] = {
     {1990 , 12180 , 5},
     {1234 , 56789 , 0}
};//initialize here, if you want to
```

But you'll have to change your `show_house` function, as arrays decay into pointers when you pass them to functions (most of the time). Perhaps change it to this:

```
void show_houses(houset *houses, int len)
{
    puts("\n\nID      Income  Members\n") ;
    while(len)
    {
        printf ("%d      %d      %d \n", 
               passed_house->ID ,//indirection operators!
               passed_house->Income ,
               passed_house->Members );
               passed_house++;//move pointer to next house
        --len;
    }
}
```

This will print out all the houses, specified by `len`. [**see it in action**](http://codepad.org/9xsH7e4x)

*Stack Overflow:*
Mind you, you may find that an array like this might deplete the stack memory. In which case you'll find yourself working with either an array of pointers to structs, or pointers to pointers. If you're not familiar with dynamic memory in C, I'd suggest you read up on that, first...
If you know how it works, more or less:

```
houset *house[25];//an array of 25 pointers:
house[0] = malloc(sizeof(houset));
//we're dealing with a pointer, and need the indirection operator here, too
house[0]->ID = 1990;
//the alternative is less readable, IMO:
(*house[0]).Income = 12180;//deref pointer, then direct access is poissible
house[0]->Members = 5;
house[1] = malloc(sizeof(houset));
house[1]->ID = 1991;
house[1]->Income = 22180;
house[1]->Members = 3;
```

But now, as I said: arrays decay into pointers, so we'll have to change our `show_houses` function once more, too. This is where it becomes a bit tricky:

```
void show_houses(houset **houses, int len)
{//pointer to pointer!
    puts("ID      Income  Members\n") ;
    while(len)
    {//dereference the first pointer
        printf ("%d      %d      %d \n", 
                (*passed_house)->ID ,//second pointer, still requires indirection 
                (*passed_house)->Income ,
                (*passed_house)->Members );
        passed_house++;//shift pointer to pointer by 1
        --len;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to `free` the memory, once you're done with it:

```
free(house[0]);
free(house[1]);
```

to avoid mem-leaks.
Once again, [**this codepad**](http://codepad.org/dOxRssrp) can serve as a working example

Comment: Very helpful and informative thanks just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare an array of structures as

```
houset  house[25];
```

and call it from your `main` function as

```
  show_house ( house[i] );
```

Answer (score 2):

It is almost as simple as with usual C types:

```
int main ( void) 
{
    houset houses[25];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        houses[i].ID = 1990;
        houses[i].Income = 12180;
        houses[i].Members = 5;
        show_house (houses[i]);
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

You also can initialize it as you do with one structure:

```
houset houses[25] = {
    { 1990, 12180, 5 },
    { 1991, 12178, 6 },
    /* ... */
}
```

If you initialize less then 25 structures others will be filled with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

```
houset houses[25];
```

And using as function argument:

```
void show_houses(houset * houses, int nHouses){

for(int i = 0; i < nHouses; i++){
show_house(houses[i]);
}

}

...

show_houses(houses, 25);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your are asking for something like

```
household_t house_info[size*];

house_info[1] = {1990 , 12180 , 5};
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the code below. I hope the concept is simple and easy to understand. 
If you face any difficulty post a comment.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct household_t
{
    int  ID ;
    int  Income ;
    int  Members ;
}  houset;

void  show_house ( houset[],int ) ;

int main ( void)
{
    houset  house[2] = {{1990 , 12180 , 5},{1220,12211,3}} ;
    show_house ( house, 2); //size of array of struct
    return 0 ;
}

void show_house ( houset  passed_house[], int size )
{
int i=0;
 for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{
     printf ("\n\nID      Income  Members") ;
     printf ("\n\n%d      %d      %d \n\n\n",
       passed_house[i].ID ,
       passed_house[i].Income ,
       passed_house[i].Members );
}
    return ;
}
```

Comment: What if OP's stack is depleted when he attempts to create an array of 25 structs? he'll end up with an array of pointers, that changes the `show_house` function quite a bit...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - This was just a way in which Nick can get his work done. Although your code is meaningful if you consider code complexity. But your code is complex enough for a begineer to understand. Thanks

Comment: @vishram0709 Yes, your code helped me out a lot and was very easy to understand! However Elias makes a good point.

Comment: @vishram0709: You were upvoted, but someone else down-voted your answer. Not sure as to why you got the DV, but it coincided with my comment of possible stack overflow being up-voted. My guess is someone found the dangers of stack depletion not being mentioned a reason to -1 your answer. (note: I did not down-vote. I only down-vote answers that are down right wrong, and contain bad, non-functional code)

Comment: @vishram0709: I upvoted as well, but other people seem to be downvoting you, not sure why. Your answer was very helpful and easy to understand. Keep up the good work and thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

create an array of the structure and pass each one or all of them if you want, into the show_house function
e.g `houset something[number]`, then you pass it to the show house function